# Download hangs using a Maven repository mirror on a kvm-qemu server

Tags: maven, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I installed a Maven repository (tested NexusOSS 1.9.1.1 bundle and Artifactory 2.4.2) on a virtual Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS server hosted on an Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS server by libvirt 0.7.5-5ubuntu27.16 (using kvm 1:84+dfsg-0ubuntu16+0.12.3+noroms+0ubuntu9.16)

Each time I want to use that repository with a mirroring setting (`<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>`), it correctly downloads some artifacts and suddently hangs on a download (not necessarily the same).

Here is a typical "console-shot" :

```
Downloading: http://192.168.1.213:8081/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.2.1/maven-release-plugin-2.2.1.pom
Downloaded: http://192.168.1.213:8081/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.2.1/maven-release-plugin-2.2.1.pom (9 KB at 28.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://192.168.1.213:8081/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/release/maven-release/2.2.1/maven-release-2.2.1.pom
Downloaded: http://192.168.1.213:8081/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/release/maven-release/2.2.1/maven-release-2.2.1.pom (9 KB at 7.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://192.168.1.213:8081/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/20/maven-parent-20.pom
Downloaded: http://192.168.1.213:8081/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/20/maven-parent-20.pom (25 KB at 22.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://192.168.1.213:8081/artifactory/repo/org/apache/apache/9/apache-9.pom
Downloaded: http://192.168.1.213:8081/artifactory/repo/org/apache/apache/9/apache-9.pom (15 KB at 14.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://192.168.1.213:8081/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.2.1/maven-release-plugin-2.2.1.jar
5 KB
```

Hangs here. In order to download correctly all the artifacts, I must ctrl+C the build, and re-launch it.

The hanging problem doesn't happened if my Maven mirror repository already has the artifacts, so if another developper builds the project after me, he doesn't have that problem.

Here is the `settings.xml` file :

```xml
<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://192.168.1.213:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```

I'm using Maven 3.0.3 on Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS.

We don't have any proxy server here. I think it's more a kvm-qemu networking problem as I've tested the same Artifactory installation on a real machine and it's working correctly...

Does someone have an idea ?

---

(Edit)
OK, it appears that it was finally a KVM problem.

First I found  [a thread talking about network freezes with KVM and ip_forward=1](https://serverfault.com/questions/154829/network-freezes-with-kvm-libvirt-and-ip-forward-1). When switching it to 0 it did nothing.

Then I found [that blog post about network in KVM](http://nickapedia.com/2011/11/28/now-for-something-completely-different-ubuntu-11-10-kvm-vlan-trunking/) and tried to changed the `model` of the bridge interface to `<model type='e1000'/>`.

Now I have really fewer freezes. But even with that configuration I still have downloads blocked sometimes...

Comment: Which Maven version are you using? How does your settings.xml look like?

Comment: How about the nexus logs corresponding to the above? Does it shed some light?

Comment: I've just indicated the `settings.xml` file & the Maven version I'm using.

Comment: And nothing really interesting in Nexus logs...

Comment: See [the same question on serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/341178/downloads-stuck-from-a-vm-run-by-libvirt-kvm-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts), as it's more a "server" question.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off AVG antivirus (Free edition) solved the problem for me. Once it was turned back on the problem reappeared.

Comment: We don't have any antivirus on the server (Linux on host and client).